# IP address on different modems/routers but same ISP neighbours

Tags: ip-address, isp

If two neighbours use same ISP but different routers obviously, and one neighbour decides to use other's wifi for a bit, will the IP address change for the computer?

Comment: Short answer: maybe. It depends on how the computers IP address is assigned on each router.

Comment: Yes;  The two neighbors are two different accounts. This would be the case even if the ISP was assigning private intranet addresses instead of a public internet address.  Even if they were the same account, the modems would be the device being given the ip address, and they would have to be different.

Comment: The question is, why are your wifi networks open and accessible?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely yes, but not necessarily.  Most cable/DSL modems have built-in NAT now, so any computer that connects to it is likely to get a private IP address (e.g., 192.168.x.z).  It's *possible*, but not likely, that you could end up with the same dynamic IP address when connecting to a different network that uses the same subnetting.

Take this scenario for example.  You and your neighbor both connect to your own ISP's.  If both computers were the first device to connect to their respective networks, they will probably get assigned the address 192.168.0.1.  Now you disconnect from your wi-fi and connect to your neighbor's.  Since he already has 192.168.0.1, you would get 192.168.0.2.  It just depends on which address you get assigned when connecting to either network.